# android place image in same place for all screens

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi i got a image which contains some random circles on it. i want to place a view say imageview in the center of that. The image is something like this

[1]http://www.kirupa.com/html5/images/randomCircles.png

When the screen resolution changes the position of my imageview is also getting changed. I want to place them well for all resolutions.

what i tried is

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/create"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="291dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="51dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/album"
    android:src="@drawable/create" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/album"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/create"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/album" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/existing"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:src="@drawable/applogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/demo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/album"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/album"
    android:src="@drawable/demo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/existing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/demo"
    android:src="@drawable/existing" />
```

i know it is not right and don't know how to do it. Please help me on this

Comment: U need to show images within circle ,right?

Comment: Center of image or Center of circle?

Comment: center of every circle

Answer (score 1):

You need to Have the images of blue circles as well. There is no way you can have each ImageView exactly in the center of each circle with application running on different screens. Place the blue circles on a white screen which will be acting as parent to ImageView and set the attribute

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

to the inside image. Only this way your UI will support multiple screens.